# Routing of HMVC routing of codeigniter extension with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have migrated my PHP + Codeigniter + HMVC (an extension that provides modules and MX_Controller) web application from one hosting provider to another.

Now the issue is only the default routes are working but dynamic routes like
`$route['miniapp/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/(:any)'] = "$1/miniapp/$2";` starts giving 404 page not found error.

The URL that I am trying to access which is giving 404 are

```
http://example.com/miniapp/user/

http://example.com/miniapp/user/1
```

It seems like something is missing in `.htaccess` or somewhere that I am not able to catch.

I went through http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html but does not help either.
`.htaccess` at the moment looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What URL are you expecting that _route_ to match? You wouldn't necessarily need to add anything extra to `.htaccess` for this to work. Presuambly the 404 is a CI generated error page, not Apache? Btw, it should be `.htaccess` (all lowercase), not `.htAccess` - if you've used `A` then it's not going to work. If you think something might be missing in `.htaccess` then why haven't you included this in your question?

Comment: Sorry its .htAccess is a typo in the question..  I have added more information in the question.